# Help with the proof of the root test

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series

Given $a_n>0$ after a certain $ν$

If $\lim\limits_{n \to ∞} \sqrt[n]{a_n} = l>1$ then $\displaystyle\sum a_n  $ is divergent.

The proof: for all $ε>0$ $\sqrt[n]{a_n}>l-ε$   $∀n>ν$
If we chose $ε>0$ such that $l-ε>1$
Then $ \sqrt[n]{a_n}>l-ε>1$. And that concludes that $a_n>1$ after a certain $ν$

Now it concluded that $\displaystyle\sum a_n  $ is divergent.

I don't understand how it came to that conclusion? Does $a_n>1$ mean that the series is divergent???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it does. A necessary condition for convergence is $\lim a_n=0$.

Comment: I totally forgot about that. Thank u so much

Comment: You are welcome!